# Is it possible to write a GLOB_RECURSE in cmake that ignores files ending in a certain way?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following GLOB_RECURSE in my cmake config to add to my project all the cpp files

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*.cpp)
```

Will be possible to add some rule to ignore certain files? I will like to ignore files ending with test.cpp in their name.

Maybe there is something like this?

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*{!(test),}.cpp)
```

Comment: Just a note from the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html): "We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate. The CONFIGURE_DEPENDS flag may not work reliably on all generators, or if a new generator is added in the future that cannot support it, projects using it will be stuck. Even if CONFIGURE_DEPENDS works reliably, there is still a cost to perform the check on every rebuild."

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try with Negative Look ahead. However it will be easier to do t like this:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*.cpp)

foreach( FILE ${FILES})
  if (${FILE} MATCHES test.cpp)
    list(APPEND TESTS ${FILE})
  else()
    list(APPEND SOURCES ${FILE})
  endif()
endforeach()
```

This way you can use sources to compile and you will also have the test list ready.